# How to remotely pull Linux metrics into local Carbon/Graphite server?

Tags: linux, monitoring, graphite, metrics

I'd like to collect system metrics (IO, CPU, NET, RAM) from a remote RedHat server which has static IP / DNS into a Carbon / Graphite server on a VM which is running on my laptop.
My laptop host OS is Windows with a dynamic IP often connected via VPN, and the guest VM is a Debian connected via NAT.

I don't want the remote server to send the data to my laptop because most likely I'll to deal with several network obstacles and at the same time, I'd like to avoid to run a remote Carbon server because I'm not the administrator and I cannot deliberately manage packages or dependencies on my own, so I'm looking for a solution to "pull" the data instead.

I went through some options available from internet, but they all assume the metrics are "pushed" to the carbon server, so I am seeking for suggestions from the community.

One option which I found feasible was to use the nmon2graphite remotely (perl script) and read the FIFO file via SSH+netcat, but the nmon2graphite did not run at all (designed for AIX), so I abandoned that option.

Answer (score 1):

Graphite is 'push' solution, it's not really easy to switch it to push model. Check ['Prometheus'](https://prometheus.io/) if you need pull.